# C# DateTime not working for MSSQL stored procedure

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

**Html:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="startDate" runat="server" </asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="endDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click"/>
```

**Datepicker Js/Jquery**

```
 $("#startDate").datepicker(
            {
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    var date1 = $('#startDate').datepicker('getDate');
                    var date = new Date(Date.parse(date1));
                    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 0);
                    var newDate = date.toDateString();
                    newDate = new Date(Date.parse(newDate));
                    $('#endDate').datepicker("option", "minDate", newDate);
                },
                onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                    $(this).datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'dd.mm.yy');
                },
            });

        $("#endDate").datepicker({
            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                $(this).datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'dd.mm.yy');
            },
        });
```

**Asp.net CodeBehind**

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    startDate.Text = Request.Form[startDate.UniqueID]; // I get startDate
    endDate.Text = Request.Form[endDate.UniqueID]; // I get endDate

    spGetReport(Tools.AbsoluteStart(Convert.ToDateTime(startDate.Text)),
    Tools.AbsoluteEnd(Convert.ToDateTime(endDate.Text)));
}
```

**Store Procedured parameters class**

```
 private DataSet spGetReport(DateTime startDate, DateTime EndDate)
 {
     // Connection settings here.. no code for simple question

     SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand();
     scmd.CommandText = "sp_Report";

     scmd.Parameters.Add("@startDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
     scmd.Parameters["@startDate"].Value = startDate;
     scmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
     scmd.Parameters["@EndDate"].Value = EndDate;

     // etc...
 }
```

Helper Class in order to get minimum datetime and maximum datetime of a day.

```
/// gets 00:00:00 of a day
public static DateTime AbsoluteStart(DateTime dateTime)
{
    return dateTime.Date;
}

/// gets 23:59:59 of a day
public static DateTime AbsoluteEnd(DateTime dateTime)
{
    return dateTime.Date.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);
}
```

**Store Procedured**

```
ALTER  procedure [dbo].[sp_Report] 
(
   @startDatedatetime,
   @EndDate datetime
)
as

select * from MyTable where startDAteColumn between CAST(@startDate AS VARCHAR(100) and CAST(@EndDateAS VARCHAR(100)
```

**Note:**
Store Procedured works.

I have very complex store procedured query that is why i showed simple code in "Store Procedured" part.**The problem is about searching data**.When i search data between **startdate** and **enddate** data never comes correctly because there is problem about **casting** or **sending parameters** from c# asp.net code behind.I think problem occurs because of casting in t sql side. I can not change cast in t sql side.I must change this in asp.net code behind.

Or

Whatever you can suggest i can apply.Where i miss in asp.net codebehind ?

Thanks.

Comment: So it comes from a textbox (text), you convert it to a datetime, pass that to a stored proc which converts it back to text. Dont you see a problem here?

Comment: Please use working code... There are lots of typos / mistake that mean this won't work.

Comment: @Jamiec what do you suggest what to change here . ı can not think clear anymore :(

Comment: You are  putting where clause on which column??

Comment: Additionally, you haven't told us what actually *happens*. You say "data never comes" - does it return 0 results? Is there an error?

Comment: you don't test for "between" dates by converting a datetime to a varchar, leave it a datetime.

Comment: @JonSkeet is there not error . Problem about casting.True data does not come.If i can cast datetime in c# it will work as true data.

Comment: @Kritner it is not possible because it is working query in other side of projects.I dont have permission to change in t sql side.I can only change this in c#

Comment: There is no way that is a working SP, it has multiple syntax errors in it.

Comment: What do you mean by "Problem about casting"? Is that a guess, or have you seen an error message somewhere? It's still entirely unclear what you're seeing. And just because converting to strings works elsewhere doesn't mean it's a good idea - Kritner's suggestion of using `DateTime` values directly in the query is an excellent one.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think i must use tryparseexact or something like this in c# code.After that i will get all data what i want to search.In this code I can get %70 target data not %100.In order to get %100 correct data between startdate and enddate , i must convert date as formatted in my opinion.

Comment: No, you shouldn't be converting the values at all. *Always* resist string conversions unless you really need them. It's not clear where this "70% target data" comes from - that's the first we've heard of it. And you still haven't explained why you think the problem has anything to do with casting.

Comment: oh... and in addition you can't have a "where between startdate and enddate", it needs to be "where date is between startDate and endDate"

Comment: @Kritner i have column over there query is about 1500 text very mix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets work backwards here - your stored proc will never work, you have not specified a field for the `where`, and it has 2 missing close parentheses.

```
select * from MyTable 
where between CAST(@startDate AS VARCHAR(100) and CAST(@EndDateAS VARCHAR(100)
```

should be

```
select * from MyTable 
where SOMEFIELD between CAST(@startDate AS VARCHAR(100)) and CAST(@EndDateAS VARCHAR(100))
```

In addition, the `BETWEEN` keyword when working with dates must be actual dates - dates converted to `VARCHAR` is unlikely to work.

Next up, using `Convert.ToDateTime(startDate.Text)` is an error-prone way to convert to a date from a string. Instead you should call `DateTime.ParseExact` (or, more appropriately `TryParseExact`) specifying the format to use.

Comment: T sql query is correct.I could not copy real code that is why it looks as wrong.However ParseExact or TryParseExact can find solution for me.what format do i need to change according to store procedured query ?